# AngularJS - Redirect if url isn't correct

Tags: angularjs

I'm building an app  in angularjs with different states and have added a `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");` to redirect people is they don't go to a state that I have set up.

Though I am having an issue when they go to an URL beyond the ones I have set up.
So for example, the following state is profile:

```
.state('profile', {
      url: '/profile',
      templateUrl: 'partials/profile.html',
      controller: 'profileCtrl',
        data: {
            requiresLogin: true
        },
        resolve: {
          $title: function() { return 'Profile'; }
        }
    });
```

Lets say I were to go to an url with /prof instead of /profile, I will get a redirect to home aka ("/").

Here is where the problem shows up: if I'd go to an url as followed: /profile/test, I will get alot of error in my console (image below)

[image: error log]

**Extra Info(from comment):**

I'll also give the server side code seeing the problem might be there with a redirect:

```
// Init Express Web Framework
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

// Set view engine to EJS & set views directory
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'views'));

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')));

// Database Connection
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var configDB = require('./server/config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Main route
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

// API 
var api = express.Router();
require('./server/routes/capture')(api);
app.use('/api', api);

// Set routes to other pages
app.get('/*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

// Port Settings
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP);
console.log('Listening on port ' + process.env.PORT);
```

and here is my workspace

[image: workspace]

Redirecting URL's that are not listed get redirected. Url's that are listed (for example /dashboard, /profile, ...) when adding something to the link, they don't get redirected. I have encountered these errors when I didn't add the controller to the main html, but that's just the thing.. I don't want to be able to surf to these links. All links that haven't been stated in app.js should be redirected.

Is there any way to fix this?

**EDIT - Added 404:**

I added a catch 404 in my server.js using this code:

```
    // catch 404 and forwarding to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

This is the result:

```
Error: Not Found
   at /home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:31:15
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at trim_prefix (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
   at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
   at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at jsonParser (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:100:40)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at trim_prefix (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
   at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
   at Function.process_params (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at next (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:120:7)
   at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
   at SendStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
   at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:245:17)
```

Comment: Could you make a Plunkr reproducing the error?

Comment: There wouldn't really be a use for making a whole Plnkr code to reproduce this, seeing it's straight forward. Redirecting URL's that are not listed get redirected. Url's that are listed (for example /dashboard, /profile, ...) when adding something to the link, they don't get redirected. I have encountered these errors when I didn't add the controller to the main html, but that's just the thing.. I don't want to be able to surf to these links. All links that haven't been stated in app.js should be redirected.

Comment: Unxpected Token "<", are you sure you don't have a trailing "<" somewhere ?

Comment: `token "<"` usualy means html content instead of js

Comment: The Unxpected Token "<" redirects to my Doctype: https://i.gyazo.com/7e00c9bd095eb90b17595b25302c4c2a.gif

Comment: And when removing that doctype, the same errors appear but for the next line.

Comment: it should be `angular.js`! Fix your server routing.

Comment: you have a route that is `// Set routes to other pages
app.get('/*', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.ejs');
});`.  This isn't going to do what it suggests (send other pages), but instead it will send `index.ejs` for ***everything***.  You aren't "redirecting" to your doctype like you suggest in your comments (that wouldn't even make sense), what is really happening is that when you request *any* file, you are getting back the contents of your index, but the contents of a different file are expected.

Comment: adding `/` to the front of your URLs fixes the problem because it causes them to be absolute; when they are relative, they *normally* would 404 but they don't because the `/*` is essentially a "catchall", and so instead of a 404 the contents of `index.ejs` is returned.

Comment: I added the // Set routes to other pages app.get('/*', function(req, res){ res.render('index.ejs'); }); due to the fact that I was getting a /get request if I went to one of my urls that I had listed. So for example: if I were to go to /profile, I would get: Cannot GET /profile.

Comment: yes, this is appropriate for Html5Mode to work correctly, but you aren't rewriting the root.  I *think* that if you use `res.sendFile('index.ejs, { root: __dirname });` instead, then the relative URLs will work again, based on the root rewrite, but I haven't tested it specifically.  It is how the ui-router team recommends though, see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: Well I simply commented it out and the states that I listed work. The ones that I don't like give back a `Cannot GET /dashboard/`

Comment: `res.sendFile('index.ejs')` sends raw template file, without any rendering. `{root: __dirname}` does not any sense, this option is `__dirname` by default. This anyway can't to serve any scripts by wrong urls. We just should use absolute urls, if we mean absolute urls.

Comment: @Claies when I do the code stated in the github link u gave, I download the actual file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Unexpected token "<"` usualy means html content instead of js.
`angular is not defined` means your `angular.js` even has not to be loaded.

Check your server and `Network` tab in the browser.
Which urls used to load your js scripts?
What response browser gets on these urls?

Fix js urls to correct and errors will gone.

You may be wrong with your `.htaccess` also.
Check you not redirect existed static files inside it.
It is `-f` flag in the `RewriteRule` directive.

---

I take a look to your bug animation :)

Your scripts are defined as `src="lib/angular.js"`.
This urls are relative, and on `/profile` page will be `/profile/lib/...`.

What you need is absolute urls: `src="/lib/angular.js"`

Comment: All the scripts that are in the doc are defined properly. I can still go to the correct urls (when stated in app.js). I am also getting a redirect for pages that dont exist. The redirect doesn't apply when I add something to the stated links. I looked up .htaccess and they state that this it needs to get added when I add ´ $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true, requireBase: false}); ´ to my code to make the url look clean, is this the problem?

Comment: Just open network tab and see, that your scripts loaded as `text/html`. Check urls of they, try to `open in new tab`. They have wrong urls, obviously. May be it's some relative stuff, like `src="scripts/angular.js"` which resolves to `http://localhost/reports/scripts/angular.js` on the `/reports` page.

Comment: Your angular is not even loaded at this moment. It has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: Updating the OP with a 404 debugger, as stated, it hasn't been found but I don't really see a solution to this.

Comment: Just add slashes to your script urls!

Comment: Yep that did the trick! You're a lifesaver. I added a '/' infront of every script src. Thanks!